# Tibco mapper activity provides no output

Tags: tibco, mapper

I have used a mapper activity.  But when I tested the process I could not see any output from the activity eventhough it has valid input.  Can somebody shed some light on this issue please

Comment: Could you please share your mapping so we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to get you closer to the error cause is starting the process containing the mapper activity from Tibco Designer and opening the console ('Window -> Show Console'). It should print out the error message.

If error message doesn't show up than use following trace configuration that enables you to examine the mapper execution in more details:

1. Create a plain text file with following lines:

> ```
> Trace.Task.*=true
>
> bw.engine.showOutput=true
>
> bw.engine.showInput=true
> ```

2. Save it and give a name, e.g. test_props.cfg
3. Go to test view and press start button (or just F9)
4. When dialog box appears, press 'Advanced' button and enter following line

   `-p <path-to-cfg-file>/test_props.cfg`
5. Start the process
6. Check the console. It should output the input/output data and detailed error message.